# Make long click act like a right click?

Tags: mouse, tablet, accessibility, click-policy

Just got my netbook edition of Ubuntu working with my tablets touch screen about 3 seconds ago... but straight away, I've noticed something - is it possible to make the right click menu show up when I **press and hold** left click, like on my Win 7 partition?

Now if you'll ecuse me im just gonna go and get mouse gestures working...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an option for this in `System->Preferences->Mouse`. Click the 'Accessibility' tab then tick the box under Simulated Secondary Click. You can also vary the duration that you need to hold it down for.

[image: Mouse Preferences]

Once this is set, you should be able to hold down then release the mouse to get the right click menu. You will see the cursor 'fill up' with a colour (by default, orange) to indicate how long you need to hold the mouse down. When the cursor is completely filled, release the mouse and you will get the right click menu.

Comment: Thanks. But in Win7, if I press and hold then drag, it allows me to drag with the right button down... is this possible in GNOME?

Comment: I don't know - you should ask a new question for this particular query.

Comment: This stopped working for me when I upgraded to 11.04. It's probably a bug.

Comment: No, our right click behaviour is a little different from Windows. In Windows, a menu appears after you release the right mouse button, which allows you to do stuff like right click and drag. In Ubuntu, it appears when you press the right mouse button, which allows you to use a menu with a single click.

Comment: New under accessibility, not under mouse...

Comment: This solution doesn't work very well, only about half the time, seemingly randomly.

Comment: for Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS: Settings > Universal Access > Pointing & Clicking > Click Assist > Simulate Secondary Click

Answer (score 4):

Go to your mouse preferences and click the accessibility tab. You want "trigger secondary click by holding down primary button".

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04**

Ubuntu supports two-finger right click on multitouch pads, but there’s no much options in Mouse/Touchpad Settings (due to GNOME changes). However it’s possible to activate *secondary click by holding down primary button* through *Dconf Editor* which is pre-installed in Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04. So:

1. open **Dconf Editor** by searching in Dash;
2. go to **org > gnome > desktop > a11y > mouse**;
3. check **secondary-click-enabled**;

[image: Secondary Click by Holding Down Primary Button]

As seen in the screenshot, it’s possible to set the **time** of long click as well.

Comment: Does this also work on Lubuntu?